# It is not changing to upper case and is on replace only pls find the eror

Tags: python

it is the code about the domain and email

```
while True:
    print()
    email = input("Enter Your Email: ").strip()
    print()

    if email.count('@') == 1 and len(email[:email.index('@')]) > 0 and len(email[email.index('@') + 1:]) > 3:
        print("Username: ", email[:email.index('@')])
        print("Domain:   ", email[email.index('@') + 1:].upper())
    else:
        print("Invalid email!")
```

i was trying to get the domain and the email separetly but it is showing the error

Comment: What is the error you are getting? what does this code do?

Comment: That will PRINT the domain in upper case, but it doesn't change the variable.  Your code would be much easier if you did `parts = email.split('@')`.  Then you can check if `len(parts) == 2` and refer to `parts[0]` and `parts[1]`.

Comment: The `while True` will run forever.  How does the code exit this ?